# how to use substance look and feel button animations?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, substance

I've installed substance look and feel in my java program and it works.

But i download a test file of the look and feel from GitHub and I saw that they have custom animations for their buttons and checkboxes when they are selected.

I'm curious how to apply custom animations for components in my program.

Comment: have you red the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)? :) post an [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) to get an answer more easily..

Comment: As far as I can remember, the animations are enabled by default.

Comment: one thing is highlighter, another glittering